# Background music for corporate video

Tags: background, music

This must have been asked before though I couldn't find any related question titles via search.

I'm looking for recommendation for a resource (library / website) where I could find composed music to be used as a background track within a corporate/advertisement video. I'm designing the sound effects and don't have enough time and budget to also compose a background track from scratch... therefore am looking for a way to pull it off as fast as I can.

Please advise!

Comment: last time I inquired into library music, I found that some of it costs just as much as bespoke composition...... anyone else with the same experience?

Comment: You must know some inexpensive composers! In my field, I'm finding composition-for-hire about ten times as pricey as needle-drop...

Comment: very interesting. wonder if there's any figures anywhere...

Comment: Brilliant work every buddy can get lots of inspiring info, keep on posting this category of cheerful articles.

Comment: this depends on what type of sync license is required and how much material is being used. As a composer and a music supervisor I work with budgets that straddle that line all the time. Sometimes it is actually cheaper in the long run to go custom, but not typically for a corporate video.

Answer (score 1):

Music stocks, i guess. Audiojungle.com, Productiontrax.com etc.

Comment: +1 to AudioJungle.  It's great for corporate.  I've got some of my own music on there as well, you can check out the link on my profile page :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this site
http://rocksuresoundz.com

I am one of the main contributors to music on the site. It's not as large as some of the other libraries out there, but there still plenty of different styles and songs available.

Answer (score 1):

you can check my older tunes, if something fits your video, hit me up on soundcloud or here, will give it away for free ;)

http://soundcloud.com/formatnone

Answer (score 0):

Hey There.
Try this site : http://www.smartsound.com/
There are some good options there.
M

Answer (score 0):

extrememusic.com, audiosparx.com, jinglepunks.com...

Answer (score 0):

magnatune.com
freeplaymusic.com

Answer (score 0):

Try MusicRevolution.com https://www.musicrevolution.com , an innovative online marketplace for royalty-free music. The MusicRevolution.com production music library has over 17,000 tracks of affordable, high-quality royalty-free production music suitable for film, video, TV, radio, website, games, background music, legal music for YouTube, on hold music and other business music applications. I am the co-founder.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jewelbeat.com/. Over 35,000 tracks and the best part about it is that it is only 99 cents a track.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://hitlist.sourceaudio.com/

The splits/stems for these tracks are available, so customization and editing is a snap!

:)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to recommend [audioblocks](https://www.audioblocks.com/).

Audioblocks is a subscription based site, with some impressive benefits

- Unlimited downloads
- 100% Royalty-Free
- Yours to keep forever
- They have a wide selection of tracks, sound effects, loops and more

Audioblocks also has a **very powerful** search, where you can search by Moods, Genres, Instruments, Tempo, Duration, etc. This will help you find what you are looking for a lot faster than scrolling through several free music sites.

Consider using my [referral link](http://audioblocks.refr.cc/KD9KXBT) to get a discount on the membership.
P.S. I am NOT in any way affiliated with audioblocks.

Answer (score 0):

The original question was from many years ago and was seeking "to pull it off as fast as I can".  So we are no longer responding to the original question at this late date.

In addition to the suggestions already posted, here is another list of low-cost or free music sources.  Note that any and all such lists will go out of date sooner or later as sources disappear and others appear.

http://www.dvxuser.com/V6/showthread.php?271789-Legally-licensed-music-or-quot-Yes!-You-CAN-license-music-for-your-video!-quot

A good source I have been looking at recently is https://incompetech.com/music/